# storing fast-changing or dynamic data as RDF triples

Tags: database-design, rdf, ontology, triplestore

I'm familiar with RDF triples used to represent facts and/or knowledge, which is inherently a graph. For instance, Google can tell me where Tom Hanks was born or even his list of family members. Such data may be static in the knowledge base.

But can facts for questions like "What is the time right now?" or "What is playing now on HBO?" also be reduced to an RDF triple and stored in the same triplestore as the static data? Otherwise, how does one come up with an architecture for storing static and dynamic data?

Or at least how does Google solve this? Try Googling "Tom Cruise" or "Spouse of Tom Cruise" (static fact), as against something like "Academy Awards 2019 date" (dynamic, changes frequently).

As I'm very new to this area, please consider suggesting me topics, papers, publications to do further research.

Comment: https://grafana.wikimedia.org/d/000000170/wikidata-edits (they use Blazegraph), https://www.stardog.com/blog/announcing-stardog-7-beta/

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. PS Time to read a texbook on data management, information modeling & DB design.

Answer (score 0):

> Academy Awards 2019 date

First things first, every year is not "very fast". What you are looking for might be a temporal database like [badwolf](https://github.com/google/badwolf)

Otherwise you can reify the statment and add the year of the event.

Or you can use a [generic tuple store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55143485/140837).